# Firebase displaying '{Instance of } rather than the field data

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to use Firestore to save collections of data for food items, each food item is saved as a document with a field for productName and expiryDate. When I run my app it displays '{Instance of 'Food'.productName}' and '{Instance of 'Food'.expiryDate}' rather than displaying 'Cookies' and 19/03/2022. Any help is much appreciated. Im a little confused why this is occurring?

**FoodPage dart file: (where the food will be displayed)**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  

    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp());
      
    }
    
    class FoodPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _FoodPageState createState() => _FoodPageState();
    }
    
    class _FoodPageState extends State<FoodPage> {
        final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _all =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('all').snapshots();
      List<String>_allList =[];
    
    Future getAllItemsList() async {  
        var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('all')
        .orderBy('expiryDate',descending:true)
        .get();
    
       setState(() {
         _allList = List.from(data.docs.map((doc)=>Food.fromSnapshot(doc)));
       });
      }
    
    @override
      void didChangeDependencies(){
        super.didChangeDependencies();
        getAllItemsList();
      }
    
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            //primarySwatch: Colors.teal,

            ),
        home: DefaultTabController(
            length: 4,
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 0.612),
              appBar: AppBar(
                toolbarHeight: 0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 5,
                bottom: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 100),
                  indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: -30, right: -30),
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 100),
                  ),
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                        ),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(
                            'ALL',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(children: [
                ListView.builder(itemCount:_allList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                  return foodCard(_allList[index] as Food);
                },),
```

**FoodCard dart file:**

```
class foodCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Food _food;

  foodCard(this._food);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    child: Card(
      child: Padding (
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child:Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: Text ("{$_food.productName}"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text("{$_food.expiryDate}"),
                 // Text("${DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(_food.expiryDate!).toString()}"),
                ],
              )
            ],)
      
    )
    )
    );
  }
}
```

**Food dart file:**

```
class Food {
  String? productName;
  DateTime? expiryDate;

Food();

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'productName':productName,'expiryDate':expiryDate};
    
    Food.fromSnapshot(snapshot)
      : productName = snapshot.data()['productName'],
        expiryDate = snapshot.data()['expiryDate'].toDate();
    }
```

**Firestore data:**
[image]

**App display data:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have some unnecessary string interpolation happening here

```
Text("{$_food.productName}"),
```

`productName` is already a `String`, so pass it in directly.

```
Text(_food.productName)
```

Also in general the `$` needs to go outside of the `{}` when you do String interpolation.

So change this

```
Text("{$_food.expiryDate}"),
```

to this

```
Text("${_food.expiryDate}"),
```

That should fix how its displayed in your app.

That aside, if you use a `StreamBuilder` you don't wouldn't need a `StatefulWidget` here and you get real time updates.

```
class FoodPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final data = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('all')
      .orderBy('expiryDate', descending: true)
      .snapshots(); // returns a stream that gets passed into the StreamBuilder

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 0.612),
          appBar: AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 5,
            bottom: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              unselectedLabelColor: Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 100),
              indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: -30, right: -30),
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                color: Color.fromRGBO(51, 171, 160, 100),
              ),
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        'ALL',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: data,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Something went wrong');
                    }

                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Text("Loading");
                    }

                    final productList =
                        snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      return Food.fromSnapshot(document);
                    }).toList();

                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: productList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return foodCard(productList[index]);
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you paste that into your app and change your `fromSnapshot` constructor to this

```
  Food.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : productName = snapshot['productName'],
        expiryDate = snapshot['expiryDate'].toDate();
```

You should be good to go.